# cannot remove backslashes added by streamReader.ReadLine - c sharp

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

the text I've got from the file has the following string: 1"-DC-19082-A3

after getting that line I get the following string (got it while debugging): "\"1\"\"-DC-19082-A3\""

as I'm searching on the DB it's not of any use like that

any idea how can I get back to the original?

I've seen that StreamWriter.WriteLine would do the job, but I don't want to create any file for this.

I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"\");
sb.Append('"');
string strToReplace = sb.ToString();
string lineNumberToSearchFor = lineNumber.Replace(strToReplace, string.Empty);
```

hopefully there's an easy way of achieving this

many thanks!

Comment: Apparently when it finds the double quotes it is adding \" at the beginning and end of the string and where quotes are, it add it twice (as you can see above in the "when debugging" example)

Answer (score 9):

It adds the backslashes to indicate quotes in the middle of the string. The backslashes aren't actually there, the quotes are.

If you want to remove the quotes instead:

```
myString.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

The backslashes are added by the Watch window.
The string itself doesn't have backslashes.

Comment: when the string has quotes it is not getting any results, here is the query:                     var queryResult =
                        from line in Lines.All
                        where line.LineNumber == lineNumberToSearchFor
                        select line;